# WinAPI: How to disable GroupBox's frame?

Tags: c++, winapi, groupbox

I need a `GroupBox` control for something else that showing it in application's window. That's why I want to disable the frame surrounding it (or at least make it invisible by, for example, drawing it with the color that matches with window's background). Both are harder than I thought though, I've been loking for the solution everywhere and found nothing. I don't want to use anything as straightforward as painting over it in `WM_PAINT`-case in window procedure because there will be that annoying sparkling when I move the window.

I'm running out of ideas, tried a few things on my own, none worked. Anyone have some tips?

Comment: Can't you just hide that window?

Comment: OK, I didn't precise it enough - it's not like I don't need this GroupBox to be shown, it's just I don't need it to be shown AS GroupBox. It's kinda complicated, I know, it's late and I start babbling. Long story short, I paint some things on that control by myself, and I figured that drawing on it would be easier rather than drawing directly on the window because of various reasons. So that's why I need it to be visible, only the frame is unnecessary.

Comment: How are you drawing over it? You might need to show some code, I assume you must be subclassing it?

Comment: @paulm: yes, I'm subclassing it. The subclass is irrelevant though, the frame is drawn separately by some default WinAPI drawing procedures. I may return immidiately from the procedure that draws the control and in the app nothing of it is shown, except for the damn frame.

Comment: So your question is really how to subclass groupbox and prevent its frame from drawing?

Comment: See if anything in here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988236/how-to-colour-group-box-controls-in-win32

Comment: >So your question is really how to subclass groupbox and prevent its frame from drawing?
Yeah, pretty much. And I already read that question and answers to it, nothing helped.
As for my subclass, maybe I need to handle some other message(s)? For now I'm handling just WM_ERASEBKGND in the subclass procedure since that's enough to paint everything I need on the control.

Comment: Looks like it needs tobe owner drawn and you draw the frame yourself

Comment: Only I don't. If I was drawing it by myself, I would know, right? I mean - I don't explicitly draw any frame around the control at all. WinAPI does that for me, and I wonder how to prevent it from doing that. 
Well, maybe I'm just too tired to think about things straight, I'll catch some sleep and try again tomorrow. In the meantime, if you find anything out, please let me know!

Comment: If you want to subclass and draw on it consider using a static control instead of group box control. The static control doesn't have that frame you are trying to eliminate.

Comment: You've got the wrong control. You don't want a group box. Choose a container with no frame.